# Scheme notation for "and" conditional

Tags: scheme, syntax-error, racket

For an SICP course we are learning Scheme and we had an assignment that asked us to check if a point was in an axis-aligned rectangular. I did it like this:

```
(define in-rect?
  (lambda (px py rx1 ry1 rx2 ry2) 
    (<= (* (- px rx1) (- px rx2)) 0) and
    (<= (* (- py ry1) (- py ry2)) 0)))
```

I did this according to my previous C habits and forgot about Polish notation for a while there. The interpreter that our online tutor program uses runs this code "correctly", as I intended. However, AFAIK, this usage of 'and' should syntactically be wrong. DrRacket points out a syntax error when I try to run this.

Then how did this evaluate to correct values for every test case on the online tutor? Is this option also valid maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for `and` is the same as for most expression - it uses prefix notation; also it can have zero or more arguments, which don't necessarily have to be boolean expressions:

```
(and <exp1> <exp2> <exp3> ...)
```

For your code it should look as follows:

```
(define in-rect?
  (lambda (px py rx1 ry1 rx2 ry2) 
    (and (<= (* (- px rx1) (- px rx2)) 0)
         (<= (* (- py ry1) (- py ry2)) 0))))
```

As to why your code seemed to work in the online tutor, it's because the interpreter probably evaluated the body of the `lambda` inside an implicit `begin` with three expression (first `<=` expression, `and` special form, second `<=` expression), returning just the value of the last condition. Although it's weird that it worked at all, because an `and` without arguments generally rises a "bad syntax" or similar error - it all depends on how it was implemented, but doesn't seem like a standards-compliant interpreter.

To make sure everything's clear, take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html?q=and#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._and%29%29), because `and` behaves slightly different than what you'd expect, coming from a C background. Remember that `and` short-circuits at the first false condition:

```
(and (+ 1 1) #f (/ 1 0)) ; will work without a division by zero error
             ^
   evaluation stops here
=> #f
```

And notice that `and` returns the value of the last expression it encounters, because in Scheme anything that is not explicitly `#f`, is considered true:

```
(and #t (* 2 3) (+ 1 1))
                   ^
         evaluation stops here
=> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(<= (* (- px rx1) (- px rx2)) 0) 
and
(<= (* (- py ry1) (- py ry2)) 0)
```

Is actually three different (potential) values/expressions. Because you didn't wrap it in a begin, the interpreter might return the leftmost or the rightmost as the value of the lambda depending on your implementation.

Your online interpreter probably implemented `and` as a primitive function, rather than a macro or syntax, or simply isn't strick about not using macros/syntactic keywords as expressions.

If the interpreter thinks `and` has some sort of value (and/or is a valid expression) it can proceed to returning the value of the first of third expression in your lambda body.